# Unable to Tap in Google Map places Autocomplete API issue with Kitkat devices

Tags: android, html, google-maps, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am using Google Places Search Autocomplete API for an Android App, it works fine with all devices, except for those with Kitkat update, like in Nexus 7, Nexus5, or other Samsung with Kitkat.

[Google Map Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)

when using on desktop in Chrome, i'm able to type in search places in input box and select the value by mouse click.
but when I do the same on Android App, tapping the result, makes it disappear.

when inspect element:
.pac-item -> tapping on it doesn't works.

I am using Sencha Touch 2, Bootstrap, and Phonegap.
it works fine on lower Android Versions like for Sony Xperia L, ICS OS and other.

working web example from Google Documentation:

[Google Places Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1)

[image: Nexus 5 Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found a way to fix this issue:

simply add this, in app.js under ext.application

```
viewport: {
      autoBlurInput: false
    },
```

as its seems, it prevents removal of focus from input, when we leave and jump on next element.

its bit complicated to explain, but it worked !

Comment: go to app.js and put this code inside Ext.application({}).